# unable to read environment value from launch.json file in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, .net-core, environment-variables

trying to run .net core test project with below launch.json file in vs code

```
 "configurations": [        
       {
           "name": "UAT",
           "type": "coreclr",
           "request": "launch",
           "preLaunchTask": "build",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/Automation.dll",
           "args": [],
           "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "console": "internalConsole",
           "stopAtEntry": false,
           "env": {
               "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "uat"
           }            
       },
       {
           "name": ".NET Core Attach",
           "type": "coreclr",
           "request": "attach"
       }
   ]
```

and trying to read the environment value using the below code

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

However always getting the null value and unable to read the value of environment variables

Comment: weird... you don't seem to be configuring it wrong. related docs: https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/debugger-launchjson.md#environment-variables

Comment: I tried looking for an existing issue ticket, but all the ones I found were already closed. can you take a look and see if any of them are the issue you're facing?: https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3ABug+label%3ADebugger+env. If you end up raising an issue ticket of your own, please ping me here with a link to it.

Comment: It works in web application but not in test project